# In VueJS using v-for, is this structure possible?

Tags: vue.js

Given a collection of objects in the data of a component:

```
data: function () {
  return [
    { id: 1, name: "foo", br: false },
    { id: 1, name: "bar", br: true },
    { id: 1, name: "baz", br: false }
  ]
}
```

...is it possible to render a structure like so...

```
<div id="1">foo</div>
<div id="2">bar</div><div class="break" />
<div id="3">baz</div>
```

In a nutshell, I need to have another div conditionally rendered at the same level as the items in the list. If it matters or helps, the individual items in the list are also components. I know how to set up the rest of the data and properties - it's just getting that additional HTML rendered in the list that I need to accomplish.

I want to avoid creating another item in the list and additional component to represent the break. No need to add the overhead of the additional Vue objects for the simple HTML div. This list may have > 100 items and "breaks" and it can add up quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should loop through the items like so:

```
<template v-for="item in items">
  <div :id="item.id"> 
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
  <div class="break" v-if="item.br">

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: From my understanding, templates can't have more than one root element.

Comment: @jtalarico Your understanding is correct. The example given is to be inserted somewhere in the template and not the entire template tag. Although you can have more than one root element with something called `Fragments`. Here is a link explaining such thing: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/09/11/vue-multiple-root-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a normal v-for and a normal v-if for your optional div

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js">
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="app">
         <div v-for="item in items">
             <div :id="item.id">{{item.name}}</div>
             <div  v-if="item.br" class="break">
        </div>
     </div>
     <script type = "text/javascript">
        var vue_det = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            items: [
            { id: 1, name: "foo", br: false },
            { id: 2, name: "bar", br: true },
            { id: 3, name: "baz", br: false }
          ]}
       });
      </script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

You should not be afraid of 100 divs or around so, a library like Vue is made to manage efficiently thousands of components

Comment: This won't render the HTML I'm looking for. It wraps each item in an outer div along with the break.

Comment: yes, but it's just a container div. If you don't want it you can use a li instead but without further context I cannot see disadvantages of this approach

Comment: It does work, but it adds more structure than I need. Especially since the underlying items are actually sub components with their own wrappers. Charlie's approach with fragments is a little cleaner.